# Link to custom php theme page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, hyperlink

I want to link a template php page (header.php) to a custom php page (cmenu.php) I made in the same theme.
I've searched on a lot of websites via google and also through the Wordpress Codex on how to accomplish this but I can't seem to find it.

In my header.php page I have a div which I want to have an url href link to my custom menu called `cmenu.php`. (I want to link it to that page to be more mobile friendly.)

I tried te following codes I found in the codex and google but none of them work:

`get_cmenu()`

`get_template_part('cmenu')`

Comment: kind of hard to understand what you want.. especially considering that you start with "I want to link a `template php page` to a `custom php page` I made in the same `template template`" .. do you want to link a wordpress page to an external file that doesn't use the wp engine?

Comment: No, I want to link the header.php page in my theme to a custom cmenu.php page in the same theme.

Comment: link as in <a href="your_page_here.php"> ? then what's the problem.. it sound more like you want to include a file http://php.net/require

Comment: @mishu Wordpress does not allow me to link directly to a custom php page in my theme folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the page you want to link to a [template page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates) and make a page and assign that template to it.
In a template page you can run all custom code you want.

Comment: I already read that in the codex but it seemed a little to far-fetched for just linking to a custom menu php page with only links in it. There seems to be no way to directly link to a custom page in the theme folder in Wordpress. Though I will take this answer as approved. Thanks!

Comment: I still don't knopw what you wanted to achieve but it sounded like your solution :)